# Почему закрыли вопрос?

Tags: обсуждение, закрытие-вопросов, причины-закрытия

Собственно сам [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/1007672/3) (закрыли именно эту редакцию). По-моему, абсолютно конкретный вопрос: «Как найти слово в строке?». Вопрос содержит *желаемое поведение* и *конкретную проблему*.

Мне кажется, что вопросы последнее время закрывают просто так, даже не пытаясь вникнуть в суть. Да, вопрос был задан не так, чтобы очень грамотно, но если хотя бы немного вдуматься то можно же понять, чего хочет автор.

Comment: Не совсем понятно зачем за ТС менять заголовок вопроса и его описание...

Comment: @DaemonHK, зачем вообще делаются правки?

Comment: Обратите внимание, что вопрос не закрыли, а поставили статус "требует правки". Т.е. вопрос необходимо исправить, иначе он *будет* закрыт.

Comment: @eanmos "зачем вообще делаются правки?" - для того, чтобы улучшить качество вопроса, сделать его более понятным, при этом не должен изменится смысл вопроса заложенный автором. Вот после вашей правки в комментарии топикастер сетует -  "это модераторы изменили за ночь", то есть он сам уже не понимает своей задачи. По моему мнению, ваша правка просто попытка подогнать вопрос под данный вами ответ. Уточните у топикастера через комментарии, что ему всё-таки нужно, в чём у него трудности в решении. Смею заметить, вы пока не написали ни одного комментария в теме.

Comment: Вы полностью исказили суть вопроса. Откатил все ваши правки.

Comment: @0xdb, Да, прошу прощения, хотел как лучше, а получилось…

Comment: Ну и перенёс пояснение из комментария и проголосовал за переоткрытие, потому что теперь понятнее стало

Comment: @eanmos  Да делается всё гораздо проще - прилител интересный, но  низкокачественный вопрос, и не удалось вместе с топикастером довести его до ума, то вы просто задаёте новый вопрос по этой же теме (но уже качественный) и сами же на него отвечаете. Если действительно тема интересная, то другие участники оценят и недобор 15 репы за зелёную галку вы доберёте на аппах.

Comment: @0xdb, не часто низкокачественный вопрос может быть интересным. Да ну, собственно, и этот вопрос не особо интересный. Просто вроде как стандартный вопрос «найти слово в строке», а хочется чтобы на все «стандартные» вопросы на ruSO были ответы.

Comment: @eanmos Да, согласен, не часто, но совсем уж редко тоже нет.  Тут изюменка - не  «найти слово в строке», а  «найти слово в строке, делаю то-то, но получаю не то что ожидаю, или возникли такие-то сложности». Может перегибаю, но если творчески подойти, то можно как минимум треть всех вопросов задать заново. Попробуйте при случае.

Comment: @0xdb думаю, не перегибаете) Мне тоже часто хочется «творчески подойти», но боюсь, что моё «творчество» тупо закроют как дубликаты)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Собственно сам вопрос (закрыли именно эту редакцию). По-моему,
>   абсолютно конкретный вопрос: «Как найти слово в строке?». Вопрос
>   содержит желаемое поведение и конкретную проблему.

Что вообще означает "Ошибка, потому что слово test в строке не предусмотрено"? Мне вот в целом вообще не ясно из вопроса, что автор пробовал, и в чём там проблема. Если бы я закрывал, то закрыл бы как домашку или "Почему этот код не работает?".

> Да, вопрос был задан не так, чтобы очень грамотно, но если хотя бы
>   немного вдуматься то можно же понять, чего хочет автор.

Вопросы должны быть написаны так, чтобы можно было легко понять, в чём проблема. В том числе потому что база знаний ориентирована на помощь будущим вопрошающим с подобной проблемой.

Ну и последнее, в чём проблема с закрытием? Вопрос закрыт как **требующий правки**, в этом плане всё правильно сделано.

Поправить вопрос -> переоткрыть -> все довольны.

Comment: «*Что вообще означает "Ошибка, потому что слово test в строке не предусмотрено"?*». А по-моему все очевидно: ТС в своей программе каким-то образом получает строку, согласно ТЗ его программы, если в этой полученной строке есть слово `"test"`, то строка некорректна и нужно вывести сообщение об ошибке. Я, конечно, утрирую, но все же, ИМХО вопрос очевиден. И также ИМХО очевидно, что закрывающим проще нажать «Закрыть», чем предложить более грамотную формулировку вопроса.

Comment: *«Вопросы должны быть написаны так, чтобы можно было легко понять, в чём проблема. В том числе потому что база знаний ориентирована на помощь будущим вопрошающим с подобной проблемой.»* если вопрос сформулирован так, что нелегко (но возможно) понять, в чем проблема, то его нужно править, а не закрывать. Для этого правки и существуют. Если по такому принципу закрывать все подряд, то здесь вообще вопросов не останется.

Comment: @eanmos закрывает не 1 человек. Если проголосовало за закрытие 5 специалистов, то это говорит о явной проблемности оформления вопроса.

Comment: Я и не говорил, что у вопроса нет проблем. Ну серьезно, проще же потратить 5 минут на исправление вопроса, чем проходить через всю процедуру закрытия. А потом еще и переоткрытия (если кто-то вспомнит про вопрос и исправит).

Comment: @eanmos как вы предлагаете исправить вопрос, когда автор даже не привёл пример кода, в котором у него проблема возникла?

Comment: Причем здесь пример кода? Автору нужно найти слово в строке. Он не знает как это сделать, какой пример кода он может привести?

Comment: @eanmos а на что тогда эта ошибка "Ошибка потому что слово test не предусмотрено"?

Comment: Я же написал, это не ошибка компилятора или еще чего-то, а поведение самой программы ТС, если в строке встречается test, выводим «Ошибка».

Comment: @eanmos ужас. Вот только теперь я понял, что имел ввиду автор.

Comment: Прошу прощения, но, видимо я тоже неправильно понял, что нужно автору: «*Нет,мне нужно сделать ограничение т.е. есть допустимые слова (например hello и world ) и если в строке найдено слово которое не входит в список этих слов,написать Ошибка*». И это, действительно, ужас :)

Answer (score 9):

Обратите внимание, что вы сами, отвечая на вопрос, давали несколько вариантов ответа - "если вам надо это, то вот так, а если то - то вовсе даже эдак".

Что уже говорит о некорректной постановке вопроса. А, как вы сами знаете, при отсутствии точного ТЗ ответ бывает один - ХЗ...

Если бы автор вопроса по ходу дела его изменил, то до 5 голосов за закрытие могло бы просто и не дойти :)

Кстати говоря, и в нынешней (9) редакции текст вопроса, как мне кажется, можно улучшить...